# AngularJS testing $routeParams

Tags: angularjs

I need to test what my app does with different $routeParams. But I can't work out how to change the params for each test as they are set in the beforeEach function.

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
  scope = $rootScope.$new();

    $controller('MyController', {
    $scope: scope,
    $routeParams: routeParams,
  });
}));
```

I want to write something like this:

```
it('resets the results', function() {
  scope.foo = [1];
  scope.resetFoo();
  expect(scope.foo.length).toEqual(0);
});

it('does not resets the results when the params are something...', function() {
  $routeParams = {}; // change this but this doesn't work...
  scope.foo = [1];
  scope.resetFoo(); // put a condition in here to get this to pass.
  expect(scope.foo.length).toEqual(1);
});
```

How to I test $routeParams and controller behaviour? Am I taking the wrong approach here?